# Use of auto increment in JavaScript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
if( !mobilecheck() ) {

            this.menu.addEventListener( 'mouseover', function(ev) {
                self._openMenu(); 
                document.addEventListener( self.eventtype, self.bodyClickFn ); 
            } );
            this.submenu1.addEventListener( 'mouseover', function(ev) {
                self._openSubMenu1(); 
                document.addEventListener( self.eventtype, self.bodyClickFn ); 
            } );
            this.submenu2.addEventListener( 'mouseover', function(ev) {
                self._openSubMenu2(); 
                document.addEventListener( self.eventtype, self.bodyClickFn ); 
            } );
        }
```

I want to be able to replace

```
this.submenu1.addEventListener( 'mouseover', function(ev) {
                    self._openSubMenu1(); 
                    document.addEventListener( self.eventtype, self.bodyClickFn ); 
                } );
```

with

```
this.submenu[i].addEventListener( 'mouseover', function(ev) {
                    self._openSubMenu[i](); 
                    document.addEventListener( self.eventtype, self.bodyClickFn ); 
                } );
```

and that way to simplify the code.

I have used

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) { code above }
```

but i get "TypeError: this.submenu[i] is undefined" in Firebug.

I am a beginner in javascript and jquery so this is not easy for me.

Comment: Your original code and example optimisation aren't even consistent.

Comment: Your last two lines of code make no sense and don't even look like legal JS to me.  You will have to describe what you're actually trying to do before we can help you with the proper code.  Plesae edit your question and supply more info.  `this.subtrigger` is a jQuery object.  You don't subtract a value from jQuery object.  If you're trying to affect the value of an object on the page, then use jQuery's `.val(i)`.

Comment: Looks like he wants to use `variable` names. Use `[]` notation instead of dot notation

Comment: i have a bunch of lines like in the first code area and i want to simplify the script by using auto-increment... the second part of the code doesn't have to be like i mentioned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you're really trying to do is to avoid repeating code and use `[i]` as an index to access each variable, then you can do that by putting your jQuery objects into an array instead of individual variables.  You can replace this:

```
this.subtrigger = [];
this.subtrigger[0] = this.el.querySelector( '.submenu0' );
this.subtrigger[1] = this.el.querySelector( '.submenu1' );    
this.subtrigger[2] = this.el.querySelector( '.submenu2' );
```

With something like this, you can access them by index.

```
this.subtrigger = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    this.subtrigger[i] = this.el.querySelector('.submenu' + i);
}
```

Note: if your first object doesn't have a `"0"` suffix, then you will have to special case the code for that object.

Comment: i am new at this... may we take this private in chat?

Comment: @unknown - StackOverflow is here for the benefit of the community.  Generally best to keep the conversation public at this stage.

Comment: ok. the code is huge (in my opinion) and i want to simplify all of it. cand someone help?

Comment: @unknown - you have to ask a specific question about a specific piece of code.  There's no other way this can work.  You can't just ask how do I simplify all my code.  If you want to ask people how a specific block of code can be simplified, then http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to post, but in all cases you have to either ask a very specific question or post the exact code in question or both.

Comment: thank you for the information. I think that the code above will work for part of the script... so i will accept your answer as the correct one.

Comment: can you please tell me how can i use the code above on     this.submenu0.addEventListener( 'mouseover', function(ev) {
     self._openSubMenu(); 
     document.addEventListener( self.eventtype, self.bodyClickFn ); 
    } );

Comment: Bloody hell, take 2 minutes and learn how to do this yourself instead of asking everyone to fix your code for you for free

Comment: @unknown - `this.submenu[0].addEventListener(...)` or if you have an index in the variable `i`, then `this.submenu[i].addEventListener(...)`.  This assumes that you have previously set up `this.submenu` to be an array of elements.

Comment: @Bojangles why the hate? I am learning by example... were you born with the knowledge? me neither... i am trying to understand this things and it isn't easy for me. if you had some hardware problems and you didn't know what to do to solve the problem... what would you do? ask around no?!? if everybody was like you...

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you for the support... but i will let this go... it seems that i am bothering way too many people with my questions.